# How can rod load reversal points determine leakage of valves in reciprocating compressors?

Tags: compressors, force-measurement

One of the common parameters that is monitored in reciprocating compressors is the net rod load. How can they show which valve has leakage?

For example, if the suction valve of the crank end (CE) has leakage, how the rod load reversal point can be affected? it goes left or right relatively?

[image: rod load]